# If $f_k \to 0$ a.e. and $\sum_n n 2^n \mu\{|f_k| \in (2^{n-1}, 2^n]\} \leq 1$ for all $k$, then $\int f_k \to 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

(Stanford Real Analysis Qualifying Exam: Spring 2012) (Ideal time: 18 minutes)

1. (a) Let $\mu$ denote Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$.  Let $f_k\colon [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be Lebesgue measurable functions, $k \in \mathbb{N}$.  Let $m_{kn} = \mu\{x \in [0,1]\colon |f_k(x)| \in (2^{n-1}, 2^n]\}$.

> Suppose that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n2^nm_{kn} \leq 1$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$, and that $f_k \to 0$ a.e.  Show that $\int f_k \,d\mu \to 0$.

---

My attempt:

Let $E_{kn} = \{x \in [0,1]\colon |f_k(x)| \in (2^{n-1}, 2^n]\}$.  Then
$$\begin{align*}
\int_0^1 f_k & = \int_{\{|f_k| \leq 1\}} f_k + \int_{\{|f_k| > 1\}} f_k \\
& = \int_{\{|f_k| \leq 1\}} f_k + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_{E_{kn}} f_k \\
& \leq \mu\{|f_k| \leq 1\} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^n m_{kn}.
\end{align*}$$
However, I'm stuck at this point.

For what it's worth, I've also thought about using the Dominated Convergence Theorem, but I don't quite see how.

Comment: Can you prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_{E_{k_n}}f_k \to 0$ by hypothesis? And $\int_{|f_k|\le 1}f_k \to 0$ by DCT?

Comment: @Coiacy: I see that $\int_{|f_k| \leq 1} f_k \to 0$ by DCT.  But I'm not sure why $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_{E_{kn}}f_k \to 0$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The splitting $\{|f| \leq 1\}$ vs $\{|f| > 1\}$ is way too crude. One would better write, 
$$
\int f_k\,du = \int f_k\,1_{\{|f_k| \leq 2^N\}}\,d\mu + \int f_k\,1_{\{|f_k| > 2^N\}}\,d\mu
$$

**First integral $\int f_k\,1_{\{|f_k| \leq 2^N\}}\,d\mu$**

It converges to $0$ by DCT, for every $N$.

**Second integral.**

We have
$$
\left|\int f_k1_{\{|f_k| > 2^N\}}\,d\mu\right|\leq\sum_{n>N} \int 2^n 1_{\{2^{n-1}<|f_k|\leq 2^n\}}\,d\mu = \sum_{n > N} 2^n m_{k,n}
$$
and we use a nice trick:
$$
\sum_{n>N} 2^n m_{k,n} \leq \sum_{n>N} \frac{n}{N}2^n m_{k,n} \leq \frac{1}{N}
$$

**Conclusion**

Taking limits as $k\to\infty$, we have
$$
\limsup_{k} \left|\int f_k \,d\mu\right| \leq \frac{1}{N}
$$
Finally, let $N \to +\infty$.